# IOS Swift card effect image is getting clipped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cornerradius

Following is my code to create CardView and add shadow effect

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    cellBgview.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    cellBgview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cellBgview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cellBgview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cellBgview.layer.shadowRadius = 14.0
    cellBgview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    cellBgview.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cellBgview.bounds, cornerRadius: cellBgview.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
    // In
}
```

This looks like this

[image]

Corner radius not working in this case to make corner radius work I have added following code

```
cellBgview.clipsToBounds = true
```

After adding above code it looks this

[image]

Note that after adding cellBgview.clipsToBounds = true card elevation and shadow is missing but corner radius appears

How to make card view with corner radius and shadow without image getting clip.

Also tried

```
cellBgview.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding `MaskToBounds = true`?

Comment: yes tried but not working

Comment: try out the solution suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `UIView` in your cell and add `imageView` in that `UIView`...Apply `corner radius` to `imageView`. Apply shadow to that UIView holding imageView. add clipsToBounds to `imageView` not to that `UIView` because `clipsToBounds` clip anything outside bounds that can be shadow as well. will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

add a uiview in your cell, lets call it content view. in this view add another uiview in which you'll add the image view and your bottom labels. So actual hierarchy would look like this

```
--Cell
  ---UIView //add shadow on this view, also make its backgroundColor to clear color
       ---UIView //add corner radius to this view and clipsToBounds = true for this view
             ---UIImageView
             ---Bottom Labels / Another UIView / Stack View
```

this hierarchy will help you to achieve the image round corner only on top and view round corners on bottom content

Comment: thats what i answered sir ... You need to encourage if someone already have the same answer before your posting its my request :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this to achieve Shadow, Corner Radius, Border in one view.

```
cellBgview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
let cellBgViewLayer = cellBgview.layer()
cellBgViewLayer?.masksToBounds = false
cellBgViewLayer?.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
cellBgViewLayer?.shadowOpacity = 1.0
cellBgViewLayer?.shadowRadius = 6.0
cellBgViewLayer?.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
cellBgViewLayer?.shouldRasterize = true
cellBgViewLayer?.cornerRadius = 5.0
cellBgViewLayer?.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
cellBgViewLayer?.borderWidth = 1.0
cellBgViewLayer?.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cellBgview.bounds).cgPath
```